# How do I undo a postconf command?

Tags: server, postfix, mail-server

I was trying to setup spam filtering on Ubuntu server with postfix and dovecot already running. I issued the following command

```
sudo postconf -e 'content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024'
```

Now I want to know how can I undo this command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `postconf -d 'content_filter` you could see default value for content_filter in postfix configuration file and from there you could again set that value with `postconf -e` command.